# Debian 10 testing, TL2019, xelatex and pstricks

Tags: xetex, pstricks, debian

with this code

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-3)(5,6)
  \psaxes[linewidth=1.2pt,labels=none]{->}(0,0)(-5,-3)(5,6)
  \uput[90](1,0){1}
  \uput[l](0,1){1}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Not correct : (Debian 10 / xelatex / TL2019 - 6 jan)

[image: Labels are not correct]

Correct : (Debian 10 / latex+dvips+ps2pdf / TL2019 - 6 jan)

[image: Labels are correct]

The log file :

Comment: Do you mind adding an image of what it looks for you now (wrong) and on the old system (correct). I have a fully up to date TL2019 (from upstream), but I'm not sure what to look for as I generally use tikz, not pstricks

Comment: If it is just the tick marks at (1,0) and (0,1) then I have them with xelatex and my TL2019.

Comment: On Mint 19, TL2019 updated today, everything is fine. The black tick is over the gray grid, but we can see it when zooming.

Comment: run `xelatex --no-pdf <file>`  and send me the created `<file>.xdv` by private mail.

Comment: How use private mail ?

Answer (score 2):

Compile TL from source and replace the "old" xdvipdfmx by the "new" xdvipdfmx. Thanks to Herbert Voss and nmarkey on [texnique.fr](https://texnique.fr)

Answer (score 0):

Too large for a comment, but here is what I get with xelatex and a fully up to date upstream TeXLive 2019, that looks like neither of your images.

[image]

MWE edited to not show the grid:

[image]

Corresponding file list:

```
*File List*
 article.cls    2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX file (size option)
pstricks.sty    2018/12/21 v0.69 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
   iftex.sty    2019/11/07 v1.0c TeX engine tests
shellesc.sty    2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
   xetex.def    2017/06/24 v5.0h Graphics/color driver for xetex
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
pstricks.tex    2019/05/11 v2.97 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
  pst-fp.tex    2019/05/11 v2.97 `PST-fp' (hv)
pstricks-xetex.def
pstricks-add.sty    2018/02/04 v. 0.16 package wrapper for pstricks-add.tex (hv
)
pst-plot.sty    2011/04/13 package wrapper for pst-plot.tex (hv)
pst-xkey.sty    2005/11/25 v1.6 package wrapper for pst-xkey.tex (HA)
 multido.sty    2004/05/17 package wrapper for PSTricks `multido.tex', (HV/RN)
 multido.tex    2010/05/14 v1.42 `multido' (tvz,hv)
pst-plot.tex    2019/05/16 1.92 `pst-plot' (tvz,hv)
pst-node.sty    2010/04/22 package wrapper for pst-node.tex
pst-node.tex    2019/05/16 1.92 `pst-node' (tvz,hv)
  pst-3d.sty    2009/07/28 package wrapper for pst-3d.tex (hv)
  pst-3d.tex    2019/05/16 v1.92 `PST-3d' (hv)
pst-math.sty    2018/12/16 v 0.65 package wrapper for PSTricks pst-math.tex
pst-calculate.sty    2019/01/24 v. 0.02(Herbert Voss) Support for caculations w
ith floating point numbers.
  xparse.sty    2019-10-11 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2019-11-07 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2019-11-07 L3 programming layer 
l3deprecation.def    2019-04-06 v L3 Deprecated functions
l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def    2019-04-06 L3 backend support: xdvipdfmx
 siunitx.sty    2019/10/10 v2.7t A comprehensive (SI) units package
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
   array.sty    2019/08/31 v2.4l Tabular extension package (FMi)
l3keys2e.sty    2019-10-11 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
translator.sty    2019-05-31 v1.12a Easy translation of strings in LaTeX
ifluatex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
 xstring.sty    2019/02/06 v1.83 String manipulations (CT)
pstricks-add.tex    2019/05/16 v1.92 `PSTricks-add' (hv)
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict    
siunitx-abbreviations.cfg    2017/11/26 v2.7k siunitx: Abbreviated units
 ***********
```

Comment: @ChristophePoulain I;ve added the package versions I used. Also note that the format I use is `LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3`

Comment: @username me too, I use the same format.
But, it's strange : some pstricks packages are older on a TL2019 update than on a "old" TL2019...

Comment: @ChristophePoulain which TL2019 update are you refering to? Remember that an debian TeXLive does probably not update with the same regularity as Upstream TeXLive, which is why I tend to use the latter.

Comment: I don't use Debian TL, I use TL "vanilla". I used the same way on my linux mint 19.1...

Comment: @ChristophePoulain that is not clear from your question. Is it fully updated? My list is from today. Otherwise post the actual log file from your compilation with xelatex

Comment: I think it is fully update. When I use tlmgr --self -all update, nothing update. So, when I compile, I added the actual listfiles.

Comment: Made.
I see something : the package repositery is http://ctan.mines-albi.fr/systems/texlive/tlnet. Is it update fully ?

Comment: I don't understand all, but, visibly, it is fully update. So, I don't see why you have pst-xkey 1.6 and me pst-xkey 1.5...

Comment: Perhaps, I have clues : my /home contains a texmf... and into the log, i see my personnal texmf...

Comment: After eliminate :) my texmf, I've the same listfiles. But always the same bad results...

Comment: Thanks Daleif. https://pastebin.com/D1iZ31vn
I hope it's help you...

Comment: @ChristophePoulain this log says you have pst-xkey 1.6. How are you normally compiling your latex? from an editor or from the command line? I'm curious whether you have two latex installations, one good and one a bit too old

Comment: I compile from emacs. You have pst-xkey 1.6 too...

Comment: @ChristophePoulain you mentioned in a comment above that you had 1.5

Comment: yes. But, normally, I suppressed my old latex installation (in fact, it is my personnal texmf who have old packages). Now, as the log says, all packages come from TL2019, only TL2019